# Arabic Numerals in Arabic Text

Tags: arabic, right-to-left

In the document below, the text in Arabic is from right to left as it should be, but the numbers inside `\textLR{}` are also from right to left, while I would like to have them from left to right, like in a western text. I thought `\textLR{}` would do it, but it doesn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{amiri}
\pagedir TRT
\pardir TRT
\bodydir TRT
\textdir TRT

\linespread{2.0}
\title{
\Huge\textsc{التزام شهادة السكنى}
}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

And this is the resulting document:

[image: Output]

Comment: The text you posted contains very personal information. I would edit these out.

Comment: @Doesitmatter Thank you, I just removed all the information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the Unicode bidirectional algorithm working correctly, you need to use `babel`. There are many clever things `babel` can now do with `lualatex` and right-to-left languages. Have a look through the manual.

Try this (with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\linespread{2.0}
\title{
\Huge\textsc{...}
}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for.